# Looking up value based on three matching IDs in two data frames -- R

Tags: r

I have two data frames, and I want to match along three columns to pull in an 'Annuity Factor' value below. I attempt to show that with a somewhat reproducible example below. I used a left_join as follows, but, in the full dataset, it duplicates every row in the data. However, it does pull in the correct annuity factor. I'm not sure what's causing it, or whether there's a better alternative.

```
df <- structure(list(TRYear = c(2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
                        2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020), 
               DiscountRate = c(1.0001, 3.0000, 3.0000, 5.0000, 7.0000, 8.0000, 10.0000, 9.0000, 4.0000, 2.0000), 
               TRA = c(65L, 65L, 65L, 65L,65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L), 
               Gender = c("F", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M","F", "F", "M","M")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df2<-structure(list(TargetRetireYear = c(2020, 2020, 2025, 2025,2030, 2030, 2035, 2035, 2040, 2040), 
                    DiscountRate = c(1.0001, 3.0000, 3.0000, 5.0000, 7.0000, 8.0000, 10.0000, 9.0000, 4.0000, 2.0000), 
                    Age = c(65L, 65L, 57L, 58L,59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L), variable = c("M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F","M", "F", "M","F")), class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c(NA, -10L),AnnuityFactor = c(12.0001, 13.0000, 13.0000, 15.0000, 16.0000, 18.0000, 10.0000, 9.0000, 14.0000, 20.0000))

left_join(df,df2, by = c("DiscountRate" = "DiscountRate", "TRYear" = "TargetRetireYear","TRA" = 'Age', "Gender" = 'variable'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have duplicates for certain rows which is causing it to duplicate in the final dataset. Try to use `distinct` to keep only unique rows in each dataset before performing the join.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  distinct() %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% distinct(), 
           by = c("DiscountRate" = "DiscountRate", "TRYear" = "TargetRetireYear",
                    "TRA" = 'Age', "Gender" = 'variable'))
```

Comment: Oddly, even after this, I still get some additional rows. My dataset has 630,600 rows and the one I'm pulling from has 504,000, but I end up with 671,464 rows. I can't figure out a way to keep the 630,600 rows

Comment: Hmm...thats strange. Can you reproduce this on smaller subset of your data? Doing that will make it clear for you as well where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

Connor,

With a `left_join`, the entire `df` dataframe will be kept as-is as the main dataframe and only when the three columns of `df` and `df2` match, per the `by` argument of the`left_join` function, only then will an `AnnuityFactor` record be returned from the `df2` dataframe. If this is what you're going for, then it appears you've setup the join correctly by using a `left_join` and this is a good way to join the two dataframes.